# Adobe AIR, External swf file when loaded from swf does not render properly

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I was trying to create an Adobe AIR application that loads an external swf file. However when the swf file is loaded from it does not render properly.

My Main.mxml file:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
            width="100%" height="100%" paddingLeft="0" paddingBottom="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0"
            creationComplete="Created()">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    private var moduleLoader:Loader;
    private function Created():void {
        moduleLoader = new Loader();
        var urlre: URLRequest = new URLRequest("Shell1.swf"); //http://localhost:8080/aps/
        moduleLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
        moduleLoader.load(urlre);
    }

    private function loaded(event:Event):void {
        uic.addChild(moduleLoader);
    }
    ]]></fx:Script>
<mx:UIComponent id="uic" width="100%" height="100%" ></mx:UIComponent>
</mx:Application>
```

My Shell1.mxml file:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           width="100%" height="100%" creationComplete="Created(event)"
           backgroundColor="0xf5deb3">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    private function Created(event:Event):void {
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:RemoteObject id="RO" destination="AdministrationHandler"
                     fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString), 'Error'">
    </mx:RemoteObject>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Group id="Group" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Label id="Introduction"
             text="This is a demo application to show that the flex based application works. Click on the button below get generate a random number"
             styleName="FilterLabel"/>
    <s:VGroup id="VertGroup" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Label backgroundColor="green" width="1000" id="firstNumberLabel" text="Enter First Number"
                 styleName="FilterLabel"/>
        <s:TextInput id="firstNumber" width="20%"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

When Shell1.swf is loaded directly in adobe air (by mentioning it application-descriptor.xml), it looks like:
[image]

But when I load it by using Main.mxml it looks like this:
[image]

So why is that the Components are not properly rendered when Shell1.swf is loaded from Main.swf ?

Comment: @Organis , could you help ?

Comment: @VC.One, could you help ?

Comment: It's the same as previous question, right? It's not that I'm full of fresh ideas here. Maybe set **width** and **height** of the loaded application instance once it is instantiated and ready to go? Maybe use **Loader.loadBytes(...)** instead of regular loading, so that external application is completely within security sandbox and application domain?

Comment: @Organis, setting width and height made the content of external swf disappear. I also tried setting the scaleX,scaleY of loaderInfo.content but no matter what I do, the content dissapears, until i remove the code where i set width and height

Comment: I suggest you to be consistent whether using Spark or MX comps

Comment: After going through documentation and lots of iteration, I have come to conclusion that the external swf file ( remote swf) must contains height and width in pixels (I mean, the main tag,  e.g. <application width=800 , height=600> , for it to render properly.